# Gradle build error around CachednetworkImage - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error when I run my flutter application:

```
  Compiler message:
../../Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-0.5.1/lib/cached_network_image.dart:199:38: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('../../Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
      oldImageStream?.removeListener(_handleImageChanged);
```

Can someone suggest what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

just add **(context, url) =>** after placeholder like this

```
new CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: yourUrl,
              placeholder:(context, url) => new Image(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/placeholder-image.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            )
```